# Javascript count two different lists, divide each and add different styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inside a loop two different lists where I have to add on the first a different style than to the other.

I need to check the last iteration of the first list and divide it by 100. 
Lets say if 7 lists are counted of first list than 100/7 = 14,28%

The second lists last iteration will not be shown, so it will be 7-1 means 100/6 = 16.66%

How should I do that?

**My Javascript:**

```
$('.item').each(function(i,n){ $(n).attr("style","width:10%");});
$('.plus').each(function(i,n){ $(n).attr("style","width:5%");});
```

**My Smarty Code:**

```
<ul class="list-inline bundle-list">
    {foreach name=bundles from=$Products item=Product}
        <li class="item">
            <a href="{$Product->cURL}">
                <img src="{$Product->Bilder[0]->cPfadMini}" />
            </a>
        </li>
        {if !$smarty.foreach.bundles.last}
            <li>
                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
            </li>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

EDIT:
I did something like this but don't know if this the best way.

```
var count = $('ul.bundle-list').children().length;
$('.bundle-list').children().each(function(i,n){ $(n).attr("style","width: " + 100/(count) + "%");});
```

Comment: its not good I think because you can divide by zero.

Comment: Thank you! How could the math work to solve it? I thought something like my example 7 lists (first) + 6 lists (second) = 13 (100%). From each loop the second lists width is every time the half of first lists width. Is that a better way? The maximum of first lists should not be more 8 than with nth a new row?